# Retrieving external applications information

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is anyway if collecting information of applications which installed on the phone?(thigns like: activities names, permissions the app using, services, etc...)

I tried to look little bit at packageManager and packageInfo.. but when i tried to use those methods i mostly got NULL.

anything you ppl know about?

Thanks,

ray.

Comment: Hi,

PackageManager is the right facility to get this information. Can you post your code to see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
 PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(..)
```

a way of retrieving some information